# GAE or just simple Tomcat Server, which should I take?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, tomcat7, war, performance-testing

I have been working on a small Web RESTfull APP that will provide urls to create user to a database and offer signing procedure (validate email/password against database). The target client to this web app will be Android devices, from my mobile application. Once the mobile app invokes the AP and response(in JSON format is received), I parse the response, and the user proceeds with the rest of the mobile app.

At the moment I am thinking deployment. For my development, the app is deployed to a Tomcat server but I know war archives can also be deployed to Google App engine.Being a newbie in webapps, I kindly need your suggestions.Should I deploy to a Tomcat server or to Google App Engine? Is any of these methods better than the other and why?

Thanks.

Comment: Finding free or cheap Tomcat hosting on the web isn't too easy. At least with GAE you know what you are getting. You can also deploy WARS the the Amazon cloud - they off er a free service for a year. ( thery call it the Free Tier - might be worth looking at )

Comment: Thanks so much Dave.I will look into the Amazon cloud.